# How do I replace a line in a text file thats not in the current loop Python

Tags: python, iteration, readline

I am new to programming so If there's an easier way to go about this, please let me know. There is a text file called `Duelist.txt` that contains the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Duelist: Seto Kaiba
Server: Amazon
Username: Kaibaman
Password: Blue-Eyes White Dragon
-------------------------------------------------
Duelist: Mokuba Kaiba
Server: Amazon
Username: Kaibaboy
Password: KaibabestBro
------------------------------------------------
```

This `changeUsername(login,duelistID,exists,server):` function runs if `login` and `exists` are `TRUE`. If they want to make the change the username it prompts the user for new username and then the function is **supposed** to change the username in the `Duelist.txt` two lines after the current location, but it does not...

```
def changeUsername(login,duelistID,exists,server):
    index = 0
    username = "Username: "
    serverSearch = []
    duel = "Duelist: " + duelistID
    search = "Server: " + server
    if login == True and exists ==True:
        print("Would you like to change this username for " + server + "?")
        print("Press \"y\" key for yes or press \"n\" key for no followed by the Enter key")
        choice = input(f'{duelistID}:')

        if choice == "y":
            newUsername = input("Please enter new username: ")
            username += newUsername
            with open("Duelist.txt", 'r') as file:
                content = file.readlines()

                for line in content:
                    serverSearch.append(line.strip("\n"))

            with open("Duelist.txt", 'r+') as file:
                for index, line in enumerate(serverSearch):
                    if duel in line:
                        if search == serverSearch[index+1]:
                            serverSearch[index+2] = username
                            file.write(line.replace(serverSearch[index+2], username))
                            

            if choice == "n":
                pass
        
            print("Exiting Edit Server Username...")
            time.sleep(1)
```

This is the user input in the function `changeUsername(login,duelistID,exists,server)`
with `login` and `exists` as True, `duelistID` as Mokuba Kaiba, and `server` as Amazon.

```
Would you like to change this username for Amazon?
Press "y" key for yes or press "n" key for no followed by the Enter key
Mokuba Kaiba:y
Please enter new username: Mokuba
Exiting Edit Server Username...
```

After the user input I get the following in the `Duelist.txt`

```
Duelist: Mokuba Kaiba---------------------------
Duelist: Seto Kaiba
Server: Amazon
Username: Kaibaman
Password: Blue-Eyes White Dragon
-------------------------------------------------
Duelist: Mokuba Kaiba
Server: Amazon
Username: Kaibaboy
Password: KaibabestBro
-------------------------------------------------
```

I've had a hard time trying to figure this out and make a simple solution but I'm just a third rate coder with a fourth rate code. Can anyone help make this function do what it's supposed to do?

Comment: The rule for editing a text file, is that you should read one file, write in a new file either the original or modified lines, and then rename the new file with the original name. You could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/55030437/3545273 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/16604826/3545273

Comment: Thank you! I will uphold that rule in my future programs. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```py
def changeUsername(login,duelistID,exists,server):
    index = 0
    username = "Username: "
    serverSearch = []
    duel = "Duelist: " + duelistID
    search = "Server: " + server
    if login == True and exists ==True:
        print("Would you like to change this username for " + server + "?")
        print("Press \"y\" key for yes or press \"n\" key for no followed by the Enter key")
        choice = input(f'{duelistID}:')

        if choice == "y":
            newUsername = input("Please enter new username: ")
            username += newUsername
            with open("Duelist.txt", 'r') as file:
                content = file.readlines()

            for line in content:
                serverSearch.append(line.strip("\n"))

            for index, line in enumerate(serverSearch):
                if duelistID in line:
                    serverSearch[index]=(serverSearch[index]).replace(duelistID,newUsername)

            with open("Duelist.txt","w") as file:
                file.write('\n'.join(serverSearch))

            if choice == "n":
                pass

            print("Exiting Edit Server Username...")

changeUsername(True,"Kaibaman",True,"Amazon")
```

I personally prefer loading the whole text file to a list, make the required changes and write back the whole list to the file.

Comment: Thank you so much! You got me over my hurdle, I did a little modification to your answer to make the function work how I wanted! I really appreciate the help, I just started my stack overflow account so I'm pretty hype that there's awesome people like you on here!

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to rephrase my Question but Pervez was able to make the changes necessary for what I wanted. I just added a little more adjustments to come up with the following:

```
def changeUsername(login,duelistID,exists,server):
    index = 0
    username = "Username: "
    serverSearch = []
    duel = "Duelist: " + duelistID
    search = "Server: " + server
    if login == True and exists ==True:
        print("Would you like to change this username for " + server + "?")
        print("Press \"y\" key for yes or press \"n\" key for no followed by the Enter key")
        choice = input(f'{duelistID}:')

        if choice == "y":
            newUsername = input("Please enter new username: ")
            username += newUsername
            with open("Duelist.txt", 'r') as file:
                content = file.readlines()

            for line in content:
                serverSearch.append(line.strip("\n"))

            for index, line in enumerate(serverSearch):
                if duelistID in line:
                    if search == serverSearch[index+1]:
                        serverSearch[index+2]=(serverSearch[index+2]).replace(serverSearch[index+2],username)

            with open("Duelist.txt","w") as file:
                file.write('\n'.join(serverSearch))

            if choice == "n":
                pass

            print("Exiting Edit Server Username...")
```

In this case, the function will only replace the text in `Duelist.txt` if the function can match the `duelistID` and `search` lines. Hopefully I explained this right.